# Multiple Statements Query not working with mariadb ClusterPool Connecter in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mariadb, cluster-computing

I configured Mariadb Galera Cluster, Everything works fine.

Single Queries are working fine with PoolCluster.
But i have problem with multiple stataments queries.

I tried to find multiStatements: true configuration in poolCluster options. But i couldnt find anything.

code:

```
const mariaDB = require('mariadb');
const cluster =  mariaDB.createPoolCluster();
cluster.add('primary', { host: '10.0.0.230', user: 'user', password: '***', connectionLimit: 10 });
cluster.add('replica1', { host: '10.0.0.231', user: 'user', password: '***', connectionLimit: 10 });
cluster.add('replica2', { host: '10.0.0.231', user: 'user', password: '***', connectionLimit: 10 });
const conn = await cluster.getConnection('slave*', "RR");
let result = await conn.query("SELECT * from tableA; Select * from tableB");
```

Error: Error: (conn=8302, no: 1064, SQLState: 42000) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near.

Note: All multiple statements queries working fine with "Pool" connection.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

The option is 'multipleStatements', not multiStatements (see in [doc](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/master/documentation/connection-options.md#other-options) )

so for your example, that would be:

```
cluster.add('primary', { host: '10.0.0.230', user: 'user', password: '***', connectionLimit: 10, multipleStatements: true });
cluster.add('replica1', { host: '10.0.0.231', user: 'user', password: '***', connectionLimit: 10, multipleStatements: true });
cluster.add('replica2', { host: '10.0.0.231', user: 'user', password: '***', connectionLimit: 10, multipleStatements: true });
```